# WPF-DataBinding-Resrouce - Applying a new value to resource does not affect binded controls

Tags: wpf, data-binding, wpf-controls, binding

my code is as blow :
Xaml:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
  <Bll:HandHeld x:Key="hh" >            
  </Bll:HandHeld>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

the Other Xaml for binding

```
<TextBox  Name="txtHHName" 
  Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource hh}, Path=HandHeldName, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

and in my Csharp Code :

```
HandHeld hh = this.FindResource("hh") as HandHeld;
hh.HandHeldName="testing";
```

this code works ok becuase my Class HandHeld implements INotifyPropertyChanged , but when I want to apply a property to the recourse it self,it does not apply on textbox es that bound to that.

```
HandHeld hh = this.FindResource("hh") as HandHeld;
hh=new HandHeld(); //this line doest not affect. why ?
```

or this doesn't work too.

```
this.resources["hh"]=new HandHeld();//this doesnt have any affect too.
```

why ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all,

```
HandHeld hh = this.FindResource("hh") as HandHeld;
hh=new HandHeld();
```

&

```
this.resources["hh"]=new HandHeld();
```

are not the same. The first implementation works with the object declares inside the code (which obviously should have no effect), While the second one, with the xaml object of the class **HandHeld**.

The second one has no effect since when you set the object, there is nothing to notify the change. So you either implement one or create a dependency property in the current code behind itself.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty HandHeldObjProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("HandHeldObj", typeof(HandHeld), typeof(UserControl),new PropertyMetadata(null));
```

Bind the above dependency property in XAML to the source. And whenever you wish to set the value,

```
SetValue(HandHeldObjProperty, new HandHeld());
```

---

**EDIT :**

I considered you had some place where you particularly wanted to bind your object to. Something like to check if the object (HandHeld object) is null or not.

If that is not the case, the code you wrote should work. Did you set the dependency property HandHeldName after initiating the class? I mean..

```
this.resources["hh"]=new HandHeld();
hh.HandHeldName="testing";
```

Comment: Ok dear Loxxy , How can I notify my form and its controls that new value is in resources["hh"] ?  how should I have to use HandHeldObj and DependencyProperty in my Case ? or how to bind this property to Xaml controls ? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Ok the way you can do this is

1. Change your StaticResource binding to DynamicResource (make sure you do this everywhere hh is referred as StaticResource)

   ```
   <TextBox  Name="txtHHName" Text="{Binding Source={DynamicResource hh}, Path=HandHeldName, Mode=TwoWay}" />
   ```
2. Remove the resource from resources collection and add the new one with same key...

   ```
   this.Resources.Remove("hh");
   this.Resources.Add("hh", new HandHeld()); //this line should take affect.
   ```

Please verify and let me know if this works.